# regex search - works in tester, not in Spyder

Tags: python, regex

Testing Regex code in online tester works but when using in Python it doesn't. I am a newbie! Any help would be appreciated

I'm trying to search for a string with a non-capture group.

I am using this:

```
z = re.findall(\d+.\d (?:dBmV), data1)
```

This:

```
\d+.\d dBmV
```

almost gets me there but I don't want the `dBmV`

to find the dbmv values in here:

```
Rx 6 Link Signal Power  2.5 dBmV
Rx 6 Link SNR   42.5 dB
Rx 7 Link Freq  407 MHz
Rx 7 Link Signal Power  2.5 dBmV
Rx 7 Link SNR   42.5 dB
```

I just want the values, no text. I can get

```
[2.5 dBmV, 2.5 dBmV, ...] or []
```

I get error at 2nd open bracket of `findall`:

```
  z = re.findall(\d+.\d (?:dBmV), data1)
```

> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Thanks

Comment: try `re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d) dBmV', data1)` and the result is `['2.5', '2.5']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression needs to be inside quotes and preceded by `r` when passing it to `findall`.

Also, use positive lookahead `?=` instead of a non-capturing group `?:` to capture the number before `dBmV`.

```
data1 = "Rx 6 Link Signal Power 2.5 dBmV Rx 6 Link SNR 42.5 dB Rx 7 Link Freq 407 MHz Rx 7 Link Signal Power 2.5 dBmV Rx 7 Link SNR 42.5 dB"

print(re.findall(r"\d+.\d(?=\sdBmV)", data1))
```

Output:

```
['2.5', '2.5']
```

Comment: thanks heaps! zppreciate the lookahead advice

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing quotation marks in your sample code. You need to surround your pattern with either single `''` or double `""` quotation characters.

Also, consider moving the `(?:dBmV)` outside of the capturing group to make it easier to read.

This should yield the results you want:

```
s = 'Rx 6 Link Signal Power 2.5 dBmV Rx 6 Link SNR 42.5 dB Rx 7 Link Freq 407 MHz Rx 7 Link Signal Power 2.5 dBmV Rx 7 Link SNR 42.5 dB'
z = re.findall('(\d+\.\d+)(?: dBmV)', s)
print(z)
```

result:

```
['2.5', '2.5']
```